# Old PayPal checkout page if using GET instead of POST

Tags: php, post, paypal, get

I'm using the following PHP code to encrypt the billing details I'm passing to PayPal:

```
<?php
$MY_KEY_FILE = "my-prvkey.pem";
$MY_CERT_FILE = "my-pubcert.pem";
$PAYPAL_CERT_FILE = "paypal_cert.pem";
$OPENSSL = "/usr/bin/openssl";

$form = array(
    'cmd' => '_xclick',
    'cert_id' => 'HSFU5KJLFS8JD',
    'business' => 'example@icloud.com',
    'currency_code' => 'EUR',
    'no_shipping' => '1',
    'charset' => 'utf-8',
    'lc' => 'DE',
    'item_name' => 'Test',
    'amount' => '4.20',
    'return' => 'http://www.example.com/success.php',
    'cancel_return' => 'http://www.example.com/error.php',
);

$encrypted = paypal_encrypt($form);

function paypal_encrypt($hash)
{
    global $MY_KEY_FILE;
    global $MY_CERT_FILE;
    global $PAYPAL_CERT_FILE;
    global $OPENSSL;

if (!file_exists($MY_KEY_FILE)) {
    echo "ERROR: MY_KEY_FILE $MY_KEY_FILE not found\n";
}
if (!file_exists($MY_CERT_FILE)) {
    echo "ERROR: MY_CERT_FILE $MY_CERT_FILE not found\n";
}
if (!file_exists($PAYPAL_CERT_FILE)) {
    echo "ERROR: PAYPAL_CERT_FILE $PAYPAL_CERT_FILE not found\n";
}

$data = "";
foreach ($hash as $key => $value) {
    if ($value != "") {
    $data .= "$key=$value\n";
}
}

$openssl_cmd = "($OPENSSL smime -sign -signer $MY_CERT_FILE -inkey $MY_KEY_FILE "."-outform der -nodetach -binary <<_EOF_\n$data\n_EOF_\n) | "."$OPENSSL smime -encrypt -des3 -binary -outform pem $PAYPAL_CERT_FILE";

exec($openssl_cmd, $output, $error);

if (!$error) {
    return implode("\n",$output);
} else {
    return "ERROR: encryption failed";
}
};
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="get">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="encrypted" value=" <?php echo $encrypted;?>">
<input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

When clicking on the submit button I'll get redirected to PayPal and can make the payment.

I can either send the form data with `method="post"` or `method="get"`.

If I'm using my code with `method="post"` I'm getting redirected to a page looking like this:

[image: PayPal checkout with method="post"]

When using exactly the same code but changing `method="post"` to `method="get"` I'm getting redirected to a page looking like this:

[image: PayPal checkout with method="get"]]

This doesn't really look beautiful. I prefer the first one and I think my customers will do so, too.

Does anybody know how I can fix that? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen your question on Freelancer website as well. For your requirement of HTTP GET:
PayPal is discontinuing use of HTTP GET from June 2017.
https://www.paypal.com/au/webapps/mpp/discontinuation-get-method

Comment: Glad helping. Ping me on my email if need any further help needed. parthodave@gmail.com

Comment: But the link you provided applies only for *Classic NVP/SOAP APIs* not for payment buttons! . Or am I missed something ?